# Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Trying to hook up a React component to my Redux state, but I am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Not quite sure where I am going wrong:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import store, { history } from './store'; 

// Import components
import App from './components/App';
import Expenditure from './components/Expenditure';
import Income from './components/Income';
import Transactions from './components/Transactions';
import Single from './components/Single';

// import css
import css from './styles/style.styl';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

const router = (
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(store)}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Expenditure} />
        <Route path="/income" component={Income} />
        <Route path="/expenditure" component={Expenditure} />
        <Route path="/transactions" component={Transactions} />
        <Route path="/expenditure/:id" component={Single} />
        <Route path="/income/:id" component={Single} />
        <Route path="/transaction/:id" component={Single} />
      </Route>
    </Router>

  </Provider>
);

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

import expenditure from './expenditure';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  expenditure,
  routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And my actionCreators.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_EXPENDITURE = 'FETCH_EXPENDITURE';

export function fetchExpenditure() {
    const request = axios.get('/api/expenditure');

  return {
    type: FETCH_EXPENDITURE,
        payload: request 
    }
};
```

Then in my component, I am using connect to pull in the Redux state as props with the following below the Expenditure react class:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('state');
  return { 
    expenditure: state.expenditure.all 
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Expenditure);
```

Any tips would be incredible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using `applyMiddleware` correctly?

[the docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html) have it passing `applyMiddleware` to the `createStore` function, not the other way around. i also dont see you using your `rootReducer` anywhere at all

try changing

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
```

to something like

```
// import rootReducer from '/path/to/rootReducer.js';
const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  [ ... ], //=> initial state
  applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)
)
```

then change your router input to

```
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
  ...
</Provider>
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, but that gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: createStoreWithMiddleware is not a function`

Comment: that because its not a function and the next line down youre trying to pass it an argument in your provider when you just need to pass the `createStoreWithMiddleware` object

Comment: Can't work out what I need to do :/ Thanks for your help mate, I will go over this again tomorrow, might make more sense then!

Comment: Amazing what a good night's sleep does! Got it working now, thanks so much for your help :)